# imagemagick quality image issue using php

Tags: imagemagick

I have convert the PDF to image,I try using the exec,by excute the linux command like `'/usr/bin/convert -density 300x300 file.pdf[0] -resample 160 -resize 512x700! images/sample-0.jpeg 2>&1'`.But i have read some articles that it slow as compare to imagick php module.so try using php with code

```
  $uploadfile = "file.pdf";
$im = new Imagick ( $uploadfile . "[0]" );
$im->setImageFormat ( "png" );
$im->writeImage ( "p-10.png" );
```

As  you  can see that i am not setting the desity and resample,the quality  of image is not good at all.In php manual also there no function that set the density,i also try with setResolution,but does not work.

Please help if any body any idea about this.
have dream day

Comment: DONE:the density can be set using the setResulotion.